Can we add Personal Finance and Money as an option for off-topic sites in the close votes review?
Currently the only option seems to be Meta. Is it possible to add Personal Finance and Money? It seems to be the most popular reason that a legitimate (but off-topic) question is closed.
I'm not sure if this is a feature-request; please edit to discussion and remove this comment if necessary.

Sites in beta don't have migration paths. Only moderators can migrate for now.

@chrisaycock - Apologies; I didn't think to check meta.SO, only meta.quant.SE. Thanks.

It was a good idea, if it were possible.
